# How to translate the following SQL into jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, jooq

I have the following (a bit complex for me) MariaDB 10.6 update:

```sql
update survey_definition sd
    join (select si.survey_def_id, si.status, si.end_date
          from survey_instance si
          where si.survey_def_id = ?1
            and si.status not in (14)
          order by si.end_date desc
          limit 1) latest on sd.id = latest.survey_def_id
set sd.latest_result=latest.status,
    sd.latest_survey_end_date=latest.end_date;
```

How to transform it into jOOQ DSL?
Is it possible?

My best (unfinished) try is:
[image]

jOOQ version: 3.12.1

Text of the DSL:

```
dslContext.update(SURVEY_DEFINITION
    .join(dslContext.select (SURVEY._INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEFINITION_ID, SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS, SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_TIME_MILLIS)
        . from(SURVEY_INSTANCE) SelectJoinStep<Record3<String, ScanStatus, Long>>
        . where(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEFINITION_ID.eq(definitionId)) SelectConditionStep<Record3<Sting, ScanStatus, Long>>
        . limit(1) SelectLimitPercentStep<Record3<Sting, ScanStatus, Long>>
        .on (SURVEY_INSTANCE.ID.eq(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID))
    )
```

The `.on()` triggered: "`Cannot resolve method 'on' in '"SelectLimitPercentStep'`".

**UPD:** I came up with the following solution:

```java
        final Table<Record3<String, ScanStatus, Long>> latest = dslContext
            .select(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEFINITION_ID, SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS, SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_TIME_MILLIS)
            .from(SURVEY_INSTANCE)
            .where(DSL.and(
                SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEFINITION_ID.eq(definitionId),
                SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS.notEqual(ScanStatus.DELETED))
            )
            .orderBy(SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_TIME_MILLIS.desc())
            .limit(1)
            .asTable("latest");
        dslContext.update(SURVEY_DEFINITION
                .join(latest)
                .on(latest.field(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEFINITION_ID).eq(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID)))
            .set(SURVEY_DEFINITION.LATEST_SCAN_STATUS, latest.field(SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS))
            .where(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID.eq(definitionId))
            .execute();
```

Thanks both @LukasEder and @VonC for help & ideas.

Comment: Have you checked out [the manual page about creating derived tables?](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/derived-tables/)

Comment: @LukasEder I have. But I don't get how to leverage it.

Comment: I mean, there's an obvious mistake in the screenshot, but perhaps, you have more specific questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query you have provided is a complex `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN` clause to a subquery. In jOOQ, you can build such queries by using the `update()` method of [`DSLContext`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/), combined with `join()` and `on()` methods for the join clause, and `set()` methods for the update clause.

To avoid any readability issue (like a misplaced parenthesis), you could decompose the query.

I will assume that:

- your `survey_definition` and `survey_instance` tables are generated as `SURVEY_DEFINITION` and `SURVEY_INSTANCE`, respectively. You need to import your generated tables. If they are not generated, you need to create them manually.
- you have your `DSLContext` available as `context`.
- the `?1` in your original SQL is a parameter that will be provided later. In the jOOQ DSL, I have replaced this with `param("?1", Integer.class)`.

The code would then be:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static com.example.generated.Tables.*;

// Assuming the DSLContext is available as "context"

SurveyDefinition SD = SURVEY_DEFINITION.as("sd");
SurveyInstance SI = SURVEY_INSTANCE.as("si");

Field<Integer> surveyDefId = field(name("survey_def_id"), Integer.class);
Field<Integer> status = field(name("status"), Integer.class);
Field<Timestamp> endDate = field(name("end_date"), Timestamp.class);

Table<?> latest = context
    .select(SI.SURVEY_DEF_ID.as(surveyDefId), SI.STATUS.as(status), SI.END_DATE.as(endDate))
    .from(SI)
    .where(SI.SURVEY_DEF_ID.eq(param("?1", Integer.class)), SI.STATUS.notIn(14))
    .orderBy(SI.END_DATE.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .asTable("latest");

context.update(SD)
    .join(latest)
    .on(SD.ID.eq(latest.field(surveyDefId)))
    .set(SD.LATEST_RESULT, latest.field(status))
    .set(SD.LATEST_SURVEY_END_DATE, latest.field(endDate))
    .execute();
```

Note: The code assumes that `LATEST_RESULT` and `LATEST_SURVEY_END_DATE` are the exact names of the columns in your `SURVEY_DEFINITION` table and that their types match with the ones from the subquery. If that's not the case, you might need to change those names or add type conversions.

As you can see, I am using the [`on()` method](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.12.1/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableOnStep.html#on(java.lang.String)) (part of the [`ON` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/join-predicate-on/) on a [`TableOnStep` object](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.12.1/org.jooq/org/jooq/TableOnStep.html), which is returned by the [`join(latest)`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/join-clause/) call.
I am not using `on()` not on a `SelectLimitPercentStep` object (which does not have an `on()` method, hence your original error message "`Cannot resolve method 'on' in '"SelectLimitPercentStep'`").

```java
context.update(SD)
    .join(latest)
    .on(SD.ID.eq(latest.field(surveyDefId)))
    ...
```

Here, `latest` is a `Table` object that represents a derived table.
So calling `on()` in this context should not trigger a compilation error.

---

> For some reason I can't do a join after `context.update(SD)`, there's simply no such method. Maybe the reason is older jOOQ version.

An alternative workaround would be to perform the subquery first, store its results, and then use these results in the update statement.
As an example:

```java
// First, execute the subquery and fetch the results
Record3<String, Integer, Date> record = dslContext.select(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEF_ID, SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS, SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_DATE)
    .from(SURVEY_INSTANCE)
    .where(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEF_ID.eq(definitionId))
    .and(SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS.notIn(14))
    .orderBy(SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_DATE.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .fetchOne();

// Next, use the results of the subquery in the UPDATE statement
if (record != null) {
    dslContext.update(SURVEY_DEFINITION)
        .set(SURVEY_DEFINITION.LATEST_RESULT, record.get(SURVEY_INSTANCE.STATUS))
        .set(SURVEY_DEFINITION.LATEST_SURVEY_END_DATE, record.get(SURVEY_INSTANCE.END_DATE))
        .where(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID.eq(record.get(SURVEY_INSTANCE.SURVEY_DEF_ID)))
        .execute();
}
```

This workaround separates the operation into two parts, and it first fetches the record from the subquery and then uses that data to perform the update.

Comment: For some reason I can't do a join after `context.update(SD)`, there's simply no such method. Maybe the reason is older jOOQ version

Comment: @SebastianLore I have edited the answer to add a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks for a workaround. I already did it without workarounds, heavily inspired by your answer. I couldn't do a join after `context.update(SD)`, but I could do `context.update(SD.join(...).on(...))` and it generates an SQL which is very similar to my initial SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem in your screenshot is just the fact that you misplaced a closing parenthesis:

```java
.join(select(...).limit(1)).on(SURVEY_INSTANCE.ID.eq(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID))
```

Instead of:

```java
.join(select(...).limit(1).on(SURVEY_INSTANCE.ID.eq(SURVEY_DEFINITION.ID))
```

Comment: That seems shorter and more to the point than my answer (I didn't know jooq, so I went long to learn about it). Upvoted.